# Cortar texto en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un script que trae todo una descripción de un producto y la misma contiene una firma, que es separada por un doble guion **`--`**.

Quisiera utilizar el texto antes del doble guion.

Ejemplo

**descripción**

> Espumadera Utilita Negra - 25128/100 30CM La Línea
> Utilità está compuesta de una variedad que hace que la preparación de
> delicias sea más práctica. -- HORARIOS DE ATENCIÓN AL CLIENTE: Lunes a
> Viernes de 9 a 17..

**resultado esperado**

> Espumadera Utilita Negra - 25128/100 30CM La Línea Utilità está
> compuesta de una variedad que hace que la preparación de delicias sea
> más práctica.

Agradezco su ayuda, gracias!

**Resuelto con la funcion explode y/o strpos junto a substr**

Comment: Mírate la función **explode** de PHP, te puede servir (hay muchas más).

Comment: Me sirvio la funcion explode , muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas el uso de dos métodos distintos:

**1) substr:**
Para poder dividir el string que contiene tu texto. Adjunto link a la documentación del método: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php

**2) strpos:**
Para poder detectar donde está la ocurrencia en el string a partir de la cual quieres dividirlo (En tu caso '--'). Adjunto link a la documentación del método: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php

Por lo tanto para obtener el resultado esperado sería:

```
<?php
$mitexto = "Espumadera Utilita Negra - 25128/100 30CM La Línea Utilità está compuesta de una variedad que hace que la preparación de delicias sea más práctica. -- HORARIOS DE ATENCIÓN AL CLIENTE: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 17.."

$posicion_guiones = strpos($mitexto,"--");

$resultado = substr($mitexto, 0, $posicion_guiones);

echo $resultado;
?>
```